# Meaning of "(universal)" annotation when tab-completing in Scala REPL

Tags: scala

I notice, when I try to tab-complete in the Scala REPL (2.13.8) to get available methods, that some of the methods are marked `(universal)`.  What is this indicating?

For instance if I type `1.` and then press the tab key, I see a bunch of methods including `hashCode() (universal)` and `getClass()` (unmarked).  (I also see some methods marked `(deprecated)`, in a similar way, but that seems pretty self-explanatory).

Comment: Universal methods means they are available on all types (to all objects). This includes the methods defined on `Any`  and methods defined in `AnyRef` (`java.lang.Object`). The latter is also available to Scala numeric types like `Int` even though they don't inherit `AnyRef`, because numeric types can be boxed into their Java wrapper class equivalent e.g. `java.lang.Integer` which means you can also call every method defined in `Object` on Scala numeric types as well.

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip why is `1.getClass()` _not_ marked `(universal)` if universal means "available to all types/objects"?  If I first do `val a : Any = 1`, then `a.getClass()` is present (and also marked `(universal)`).

Comment: Because it's not available directly, but indirectly via autoboxing to `java.lang.Integer`. `Int` is not a descendant of `Object`, because it's mapped to a Java primitive `int`. But `"foo". getClass()` is marked `(universal)` because `String` is a descendant of `Object`, so it's available directly. It should not matter that much either way.